# how to return false if no records exist in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

Want to check if any records exist in ClientAccessCode table, if not return false...

```
if (!CheckAccessCodeExists())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client Access code does not exist");
    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Client Access code does not exist");
}

private static bool CheckAccessCodeExists()
{
    using (EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities())
    {
        ClientAccountAccess clientAccess = db.ClientAccountAccesses
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                .Take(1)
                .Single();

        if (clientAccess != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

//this is flagging sequence contains no elements, in the lamba expression, so how can I just return false then? some use of .Any() perhaps?

thanks

**EDIT**
Thats great thanks for the help guys il mark the answer now, also another query if I had

```
ClientAccountAccess clientAccess = db.ClientAccountAccesses
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                  .Take(1)
                  .Single();

if (clientAccess != null)
{
    db.DeleteObject(clientAccess);
}
```

how can I refactor this to say something tidier like

```
if (db.ClientAccountAccesses.Any())
{
    db.DeleteObject(//what does in here do I have to use above code to get record to delete?);
}
```

Comment: To just delete everything?

Comment: well considering there will only ever be one record in the table, yea delete the record, but not the actual table

Answer (score 0):

```
private static bool CheckAccessCodeExists()
    {
        using (EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities())
        {
            var item = db.ClientAccountAccesses.FirstOrDefault();
            if(item != null)
            {
               db.Remove(item);
               db.SaveChanges(); 
               return true;                 
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Updated Solution for your edit. Down voter(s) please comment.

Comment: ah yeah, updated when playing around forgot to change back. fixed. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects there to be *at least* one item in the collection, if it doesn't find 1 then it throws an exception. If it's possible for your collection to not have a record then you should be using [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - this will return the default value for the type you are working with, in your case this will return `null`.

```
ClientAccountAccess clientAccess = db.ClientAccountAccesses
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Take(1)
    .SingleOrDefault();

if (clientAccess != null)
{
    db.DeleteObject(clientAccess);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're reading past the literal text of the question and getting to the heart of it.  I'd add that you could certainly wrap Single in a try-catch (I wouldn't *recommend* that approach but it's good to know your options).

Comment: Seems that you make 4 queries in order to perform delete single record  and also no db.SaveChanges() method.

Comment: @NikolaMitev please point out the 4 queries because I only see 1 (2 when you call SaveChanges)? Yep I deliberately left it out because that's not what I was trying to demonstrate

Answer (score -1):

```
    private static bool CheckAccessCodeExists()
    {
        using (EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities())
        {
            var item = db.ClientAccountAccesses.FirstOrDefault();
            if (item != null)
            {
                db.DeleteObject(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }             
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Seems wasteful to perform 3 queries when you can get away with 2, also this checks if there is *any* records exist, the OP is looking to check whether a *specific* record already exists.